# Qt program does not run and exits immediately when run on another computer

Tags: qt, deployment

I want to deploy my QT program and I can't find the reason it doesn't work, maybe you guys can help me ?

I work with visual studio 2010, windows 7, QT 5.0.2.

I have tested my deployment tree on my own computer and it works fine.

When deploying my application I ship every necessary dll that I am aware of. Depends.exe does not complain. I also deployed the plugin I know of, and since it still did not work I moved my entire plugin folder in the exe folder.

When I execute it on any other computer than my development computer, the program exits instantaneously with no message whatsoever.

Any idea where I should look now ?

How can I debug that kind of issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try deploying the debug version of the program and then starting it from the command line.  The debug version will output more information to the console which could help you resolve the issue.

You will have to also deploy the debug versions of the MS c-runtime libraries.

Deploying the debug version is not a permanent solution, so you should not adopt that as normal routine for distributing your software.  I am just suggesting that you try running the debug version one time on that particular machine until you figure out the issue.  Then remove the installed program and install the release version again.

Comment: Thank you it worked : I had an helpful message this way (could not load windows plugin available plugins : windows). As it turns out I did not have the dependencies for this plugin, now it works, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can run your application using QtCreator:

Debug > Start Debugging > Start and Debug External Application...

This can give you more information about what's going on.